# How to look up the value of a row/column combination in a matrix (R)?

Tags: r, database, lookup

I have the following look up problem in R (but I am not sure whether I use this term 100% correctly). Given is a `matrix` with data points, where row and column names are identical and in the same order (as in e.g., a covariance matrix). Also given is a `data.frame` of row and column name pairs for which the corresponding value should be looked up in the matrix.

To illustrate (and using a non-symmetric matrix for generality):

```
set.seed(1)
m = matrix(1:25,5,5)
colnames(m) <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
rownames(m) <- c("A","B","C","D","E")

l <- matrix(ncol=2,nrow=5)
for(i in 1:5){
  l[i,] <- sample(c("A","B","C","D","E"),2,replace = FALSE) #choose TRUE if diagonal elements should be included in the list
}
l <- as.data.frame(l)
colnames(l) <- c("row","column")
```

So we have matrix ´m´ and data.frame `l` (the equal number of rows of `m` and `l` are coincidental and `nrow(l)` could be much higher, though redundant pairs surely occur for `>25`):

```
  A  B  C  D  E
A 1  6 11 16 21
B 2  7 12 17 22
C 3  8 13 18 23
D 4  9 14 19 24
E 5 10 15 20 25

  row column
1   B      E
2   C      D
3   B      D
4   E      C
5   D      A
```

And we seek an algorithm that finds:

```
> c(22,18,17,15,4)
```

I'd be happy to pointers how this problem is referred correctly to and practical solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use matrix subsetting on the row names as follows:

```
m[cbind(as.character(l$row), as.character(l$column))]
[1] 22 18 17 15  4
```

From the help file `help("[")`, it says:

regarding matrix subsetting:

> When indexing arrays by [ a single argument i can be a matrix with as many columns as there are dimensions of x; the result is then a vector with elements corresponding to the sets of indices in each row of i.

Also, regarding character subsetting:

> Character vectors will be matched to the names of the object (or for matrices/arrays, the dimnames).

These two features combine to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: That help file is certainly worth the time to go through. It has a some hidden jems.